# Jasper token based authentication with internal users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jasperserver

I have a jasper server 6.3 commercial version. I have created set of users in jasper. Also I have a an application where the same users will be authenticated and have the auth token. I need to pass the token with the request to jasper and login by that user. without getting the login screen,

I read the [token based authentication cookbook](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-authentication-cookbook/v56/token-based-authentication#Mapping2) and it only covers the authentication with external users who are not previously created in jasper.

I thought of putting a custom authentication provider for this. would that be a good option ?

Please help.

Thanks.
Thusira.